# Cannot get or set value in parameters Map for sendkeys command

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, qaf

[myParam variable structure]

I got a Map<String, Object> return from a command, it is a kind of Map<key, value>.My problem is looks simple, but it have taken me 4 days, I cannot get or set the content of "value" key. Below is my variable that I debug in Java, it looks like (you can see my screen shot for more visual)

myParam

```
-[0]
--key: "value"
--value: CharSequence[1]
---[0]: "abcdefghijkl"  <--- I need to change this 
-[1]
--key:"id"
--value: 152438043653703040
```

My intenstion is change or get the value of "value" key, so I just set/get by `myParam.put("value","new content")`
But Java always changes the text CharSequence[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwPf4.png), not the text "abcdefghijkl".
Could you please tell me how to get or set the text "abcdefghijkl". All what I want is changing the text "abcdefghijkl" to a new text.
All things I have done so far but still not get it works:

1. Declare a CharSequence then get return `myParam.get("value")`, the string return still is CharSequence [refer scereenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwPf4.png)
2. using `myParam.put("value","new content")`, it will change CharSequence to "new content", this is absolute not my demand

Please help me out of this situation. it drives me crazy now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please paste your script/code also.

Comment: Yes, you can see my source code below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you are trying to access value to be passed in sendkeys element command. If you see [signature of sendkeys](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) it has optional array of `CharSequence`. So as value you Will get array of `CharSequence`.

To get value

```
CharSequence val = ((CharSequence [])myParam.get("value"))[0];
```

To set value

```
((CharSequence [])myParam.get("value"))[0]="new content";
```